# MVC View passing Model info for hyperlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have something like the following in my MVC View:

```
  <div>
     <a href="http://www.abcinc.com/Web/about.pdf" class="hypLnk1" download=about.pdf>Download</a>
 </div>
```

What I like to do is to pass a value for the pdf file name from the controller so it looks something like this:

```
  <div>
     <a href="http://www.abcinc.com/Web/"@Model.FileName class="hypLnk1" download=@Model.FileName>Download</a>
 </div>
```

WHen I did this I get:

http://www.abcinc.com/Web/

even though Model.FileName has a value.

Comment: Use `href="http://www.abcinc.com/Web/@Model.FileName" ` place quotes properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the double quotes properly for the `href` property.

```
 <div>
     <a href="http://www.abcinc.com/Web/@Model.FileName" 
                  class="hypLnk1" download=@Model.FileName>Download</a>
 </div>
```

Also make sure that your `FileName` property value does not have a `space` inside it. If there is a space, the url will break.

Answer (score 0):

Include parenthesis after the @ razor keyword and include the server side code inside the quotes

```
<div>
    <a href="http://www.abcinc.com/Web/@(Model.FileName)" class="hypLnk1" download=@(Model.FileName)>Download</a>
</div>
```